# target specific div that is inside a href and all that is wrapped with main div for hover in css

Tags: html, css, hover

How to target a div to do a hover effect that is wrapped  inside a href and all that sits inside main div like a holder? When the user hover on the item,i want  for example the p element to have hover effet that it is inside div el with class item.
How to target elements like this? If it's possible to do only with css?
Something like this

```
<div id="ItemsEmployees">
<a href="">
    <div class="itemHolder">

        <div class="nameTitle">

        </div>
        <div class="item">
        <p>I want only this div to  have  hover style</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.item:hover`? Just select by class

Comment: I tried, but that will do a hover effect only when i am hovering  directly .item element,

Comment: That's the point, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, i want the hover effect to appear when i am hovering whole a  href tag, and only then the  effects of .item div to appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a descendant selector to select it. Here is some code:

```
<div id="ItemsEmployees">
    <a id="anchor" href="">
        <div class="itemHolder">
            <div class="nameTitle"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>I want only this div to  have  hover style</p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

And then some CSS:

```
#anchor:hover .item {
    /* Do stuff here */
}
```

What this does is select `#anchor` (which is link, I added an ID) and when it hovers, effects `.item`, which is the paragraph element.

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wagiladuge/edit?html,css,output) demonstrating with `font-size`.

Comment: Thank  you so much for this.

Answer (score -3):

Using jquery.

```
$('#ItemsEmployees a').hover(function(){
$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
})
```

Here div tag is parent and anchor tag is child of div tag, so all anchor tag inside the parent div tag is bindend with hover effects.

Comment: But the question doesn't mention jQuery.